# Can I use Tornado for parsing json-rpc to web-frontend?

Tags: python-3.x, tornado, json-rpc

I'm trying to connect to a server called [Moonraker](https://github.com/Arksine/moonraker) and communicate to it with json-rpc. I think I have solved that task with Tornado, but I also want to create a web UI on port 8080 also with Tornado but in another instance.

What is the best way to do this?:

1. Start a Tornado Io-loop that connects to port localhost:7125, keeps the connection open and send diffrent json-rpc commands to it.
2. Start another Tornado instance that serves a webpage on port 8080. This page will I use for a UI to send and receive the json-rpc commands that coming from the first Tornado instance.

I hope you can understand what I want to create.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Tornado-RPC](https://github.com/joshmarshall/tornadorpc) module. It supports jsonrpc. You can fork and improve it.
Also you can combine twisted and tornado, and use twisted for rpc and tornado for websockets.